# Products not found: multi-storeview in subdirectories

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, products, store-view

Searched to forums for hours, non of the answers works for me.

My setup:

- I have a php file that maps the store URL's to the correct store views (type = store)
- Each language (store view) is a subdirectory of it's language code. Subdirectories exists with the index.php file using the url mapper php file. .htaccess logic is done with nginx:

location ~ ^/(?(nl|de|fr|en)) {
    rewrite / /$uri_prefix/index.php break;
    echo_exec @phpfpm;
}

- Most of the product attributes are set to "use default value" except for some text attributes that need to be translated. (description, name etc)

Everything works fine (pages / categories etc) except for the fact that no products show up anywhere. I first thought that is was a redirect problem but again, category pages etc. show up correctly for each view.

Product attributes checked and correct:

- **Status**: All enabled correctly (store views: use default)
- **Visibility**: Config products: Catalog, Search & Single products: not visible
- **Category**: Config products attached correctly
- **Website**: All good (both config and single)
- **Inventory**: All around 100+ (nog actually used)
- **IsInStock**: All ok!

I'm out of ideas... if anyone has one, please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a DB problem.
When moving a DB the default customer group ID (0) was changed.